# Setup Rails 3 App on Production Server (no compiler/root access)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, rubygems

I'm trying to set up a rails app on a production box (no compiler, no root access) that's running Mac OS X Server 10.6.6. It's got ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0], and gem 1.3.5. However I need to install a newer version of rubygems because I need Rails 3 and Bundler. I can't update the system ruby or rubygems.

I tried installing a local version of rubygems (v 1.7.2) but 'gem -v' still returns 1.3.5. 'which gem' definitely points to my local rubygems binary. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the output from 'gem env':

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /.gem/ruby/1.8/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /.gem/ruby/1.8/gems
     - /.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/

Addition:
When I run `gem update --system` I get the following error:

```
Updating RubyGems  
Updating rubygems-update  
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.8.5  
Updating RubyGems to 1.8.5  
Installing RubyGems 1.8.5  
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)  
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/gauntlet_rubygems.rb  
RubyGems system software update
```

It still reports running version 1.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your PATH to prefer your local gem 1.7.2 binary over the default? E.g. if you installed the 1.7.2 binary in `~/bin`, you'd want to update your `.bash_profile` with `export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"`.

Run `which gem` to find out which gem binary you are calling when you run `gem env`.

Comment: Yes my path is set correctly, 'which gem' returns the path to my local gem installation.

Answer (score -1):

Can you install rvm on the server?  If so then you can run inside your own app-specific rvm and have whatever gems/rubygems you want inside that.

Comment: If he doesn't have a compiler, he won't be able to compile any rubies for rvm.